# add WordPress editor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

This is how I add custom taxonomy

```
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'supports' => array( 'editor', 'thumbnail')
);
register_taxonomy( 'bookwriters', 'product', $args );
```

I want add WordPress editor on description how i can do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this :

```
/**
 * TinyMCE editor in taxonomy page
 */
function o99__category_editor() {
    global $pagenow, $current_screen;

    if( $pagenow == 'edit-tags.php' ) {
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/post.php'); // we need these
        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/template.php');

        wp_tiny_mce( false, array( 'editor_selector' => 'description', 'elements' => 'description', 'mode' => 'exact' )); // first argument TRUE will give the light version
    } 
}
add_action( 'init', 'o99__category_editor' );
```

I did not really tested it, but something along these lines should work.
Also since the TinyMCE editor was dropped as default, , you might need to get the Classic Editor plugin. Also not tested.